# What is the best suggestion for "iteration" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

La gugla tradukilo sugestis *ripeton* tamen mi dubas ke gxi estas perfekta. 
En mia gepatra lingvo (la cxina)  "iteration" enhavas ripetadon kaj anstatauxigon.
     Mi bezonas rekomendo de denaskuloj de angla lingvo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tie estas miaj preferataj elektoj por temaj nocioj, laŭ kunteksto:

- continue (jump to next iteration of current loop): sekvigi/(cikl)sekvitiraci
- enumerator : enumeraciilo/iteraciilo
- iterate : tracikli (ĉar tio estas pri cikli tra vicon)
- iterator : laŭciklilo/iteraciilo
- loop: ciklilo/itaraciilo
- loop statement: cikla ordono/iteracio

Answer (score 5):

Tio dependas de la kunteksto, sed vidu en PIV: [Iteracio](http://vortaro.net/#iteracii)